# When using the fill method, how do I choose the button to press?

Tags: casperjs

I want to fill a form then press a specific button. Is it possible to choose the button using [casper.fill](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.fill) method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly with the `fill()` method, bu with the `click()` one:

HTML:

```
<form name="plop">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" name="foo" value="Foo!">
    <input type="submit" name="bar" value="Bar!">
</form>
```

Casper script:

```
// casperjs script
casper.fill('form[name="plop"]', {
    q: 'yeah',
});
casper.click('input[type="submit"][name="bar"]');
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up using. But I guess I'll submit a feature request to pass a selector instead of True as the third parameter.